# 403 Forbidden and 404 Not Found on Nginx Ubuntu Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, http, ubuntu, nginx, http-status-code-404

Persistent 403 and 404 errors on a WordPress website.
Here's what I've confirmed so far:

All WordPress files are correctly installed in the /var/www directory.
The server has full permissions for the directory containing the WordPress files.
The server configuration file (included below) appears to be correctly set up.
Despite these checks, I'm still encountering 403 and 404 errors when trying to access my website. I would appreciate any assistance in troubleshooting and resolving this issue.

Here's my Nginx server configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name zakiyadavidson.com www.zakiyadavidson.com;
    return 300 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate 
/etc/letsencrypt/live/zakiyadavidson.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by 
Certbot
ssl_certificate_key 
/etc/letsencrypt/live/zakiyadavidson.com/privkey.pem; # managed by 
Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

server_name zakiyadavidson.com www.zakiyadavidson.com;
root /var/www/zakiyadavidson.com;
index index.php;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }

#removed node.js server info from here

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/\.user\.ini {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example URL that you tried to access?

Comment: When hitting the URL mentioned in your question, I get a message from DreamHost saying "zakiyadavidson.com is almost here!" It has a valid LetsEncrypt cert dated July 8. I suspect your next call should be to DreamHost support.

Comment: Hi @LajosArpad and O. Jones- I’ve moved [link](zakiyadavidson.com) back to DreamHost as that is its origin to rebuild the site.  I am happy to move it back so you can see the issue.  It will take some time for the DNS to propagate. I received the ssl from  [link] (https://certbot.eff.org/) and it is valid for another year.

Comment: @O.Jones The 403 error is now showing at zakiyadavidson.com.

Comment: I got the error fixed by changing the permissions on the www folder and then moving all WordPress files out of the folder to fix the 404 at /wp-admin.